# Capybara Button JS Response ActionController Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I'm writing some tests for my project and having some issues.  In the test, I'm just filling some fields and I want to submit this form. It works in the browser but in the test, I got a `formatError`.  Here is the Error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat:  CompaniesController#update is missing a template for this request format and variant.
>
> request.formats: ["text/html"]
> request.variant: []

The little test:

```
scenario 'update company with valid params' do
  visit company_account_information_path

  fill_in 'company_name', with: "Mustername für Firma"
  fill_in 'company_owner_name', with: "Mustermann"

  click_button "Speichern"
end
```

I didn't add some expectations yet because it is failing every time.

**EDIT:**

Yes, the response is js! It should open a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To js tests you need to specify `js: true` in scenario and should config a webdriver like selenium or poltergeist to execute js with capybara.

Your test:

```
scenario 'update company with valid params', js: true do
  visit company_account_information_path

  fill_in 'company_name', with: "Mustername für Firma"
  fill_in 'company_owner_name', with: "Mustermann"

  click_button "Speichern"
end
```

Read this doc to configure a webdriver that supports js [Capybara drivers](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers)

Comment: Exactly correct - the OP is running tests that require JS using a driver that doesn't support JS